# Merge two Jenkins pipeline builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to merge two builds or to have a workflow in Jenkins. We are trying to implement a Jenkins Pipeline over our current SLDC.  The issue is as follows.

[image]
A38298 - Code was written by 'John Doe', was built March 2nd (bottom build) and was placed into IQA.

A38298 - Code was written by 'Jane Buck', was built March 3rd (top build) and placed into IQA.

Since these are under the same 'task' once they are placed in IQA (Internal QA) the code is then 'merged' so when moving up to UAT and on, they will be brought together.

I would like a way to display that either they are merged or have one branch 'take over' the other.  Really I would like some way to show that these two are together. In the picture shown, it shows the 'failed' message, which in most cases is not true. Note: this process is not using GIT or SVN.  But it is using a file locking version control system.

Comment: Have you considered using the [Join plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin)?